# Можно ли на лету менять ПРОПИСНЫЕ на строчные буквы в названиях категорий WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, функции, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Всем добра! Ситуация следующая:

Есть сайт на WP + WooCommerce. Каталог наполняется путём импорта из 1Ски. Все категории в 1Ске названы ПРОПИСНЫМИ буквами, соответственно на сайт всё также выгружается ПРОПИСНЫМИ. Менял вручную на строчные, но естественно при следующем импорте всё обратно вернулось.
Есть какая-нибудь функция или плагин, который бы на лету при импорте или после импорта менял названия категорий на нормальные?

P.s. Менять в 1Ске названия категорий клиент отказывается(

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно лишь отображать строчный буквы, то можете использовать [CSS text-transform](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_text_transformation.asp).

Если нужно хранить данные в нижнем регистре, то можно сделать предобработку файла импорта при помощи консольной команды `sed -e 's/[A-ZА-Я]/\L&/g'`.

Пример:

```
echo ПРИВЕТ | sed -e 's/[A-ZА-Я]/\L&/g'
```